# Connect android app to sockjs server

Tags: android, sockets, sockjs

I am working on a native android app,
I have to connect my app to Sockjs server.
I tried to connect with Socket.IO, Autobahn, WebSockets, but its not connecting.
Is there any sockjs client for android?
Please help, Thanks.

Socket.IO :

```
private void connectToSocket(String serverUrl, String accessKey) {
    IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
    opts.forceNew = true;
    opts.reconnection = true;
    //opts.query = "accessKey="+accessKey;
    String host = serverUrl;

    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket(host, opts);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
    mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
    mSocket.on("new message", onNewMessage);
    mSocket.connect().emit("accessKey", accessKey);
    if (mSocket.connected()) {
        Log.d("SocketMsg: ", "Connected");
    }

}

private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {

    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("SocketMsg: ", args[0].toString());
                //mSocket.emit("accessKey", accessKey);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Connect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (Object o : args) {
                    Log.i("IO " + Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, o.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("SocketMsg: ", args[0].toString());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                for (Object o : args) {
                    Log.i("IO " + Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, o.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Its giving 'xhr poll error'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now connected successfully to SockJS using the following trick :).

```
1. Place a web view and set its visibility to gone.
2. Use SockJS client in webview.
3. Create a javascript Interface that send data back to native code when get data from socket.
4. We have to call the function only once from native code.
```

JavaScript Interace:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /**
     * Instantiate the interface and set the context
     */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /**
     * Show a toast from the web page
     */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void msg(final String toast) {
        Log.d("msg: ", toast);
        if (toast.contains("{"))
            createMarkerList(toast);
    }
}
```

SockJS Client on Webview :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function connectToSocket(url, accessKey){
        Android.msg(String("called"));
        var sock = new SockJS("http://api.example.in:8182/realtime");
        sock.onopen = function() {
            Android.msg("open");
            sock.send(JSON.stringify({
              key: accessKey
            }));
        };

        sock.onclose = function() {
            Android.msg("close");
        };

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
            result = e.data.replace(/,\s*$/, '');
            Android.msg(String(result));
        };

        sock.onerror = function(e) {
            Android.msg("error");
        };
    }
</script>
```

Calling js function :

```
webView.loadUrl(javascript:connectToSocket(url, accessKey));
```

Comment: I also wrote a client for sockJs :
https://github.com/vishal-raj/SockJsClientAndroid

Comment: Is there a way to send message to server using your sockjs client in android?

Comment: implement sock.send('') function.

Comment: Do I have to make a paramatrized function with sock.send() in temple.html and call that function from Android?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you used `socket.io`.

There's a a good sample for both client and server at the [Socket.io Blog](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/#)